# conflict installing pytorch and torchvision using conda install

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to install specific versions of pytorch and torchvision but everytime i try install it with conda I face this Conflict Regarding python and cudatoolkit versions

```
`newstudent@snail-System-Product-Name:~$ conda install pytorch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.1 cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch`

`Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.`

`Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`

`Solving environment: \` 

`Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed`                                                                        

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - torchvision==0.4.1 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
python=3.8 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
cudatoolkit=11.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
pytorch==1.2.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]

Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
pytorch==1.2.0 -> cffi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
pytorch==1.2.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
cudatoolkit=11.0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
python=3.8 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
torchvision==0.4.1 -> numpy[version='>=1.11'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
python=3.8 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']`
```

Anyone can help with this?

Comment: Have the same problem. Anaconda create env with torch=2.0.1 automaticaly
And I cant install packages wich uses low version.
IDK what to do.
Byt the desigin is - do not use Anaconda ...(